# How set store unique data in java

Tags: java, set

I want to know how set store unique data not duplicate value in java?Is there any mechanism the set folow when it store data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`java.util.Set#add(E)` internally calls `jav.util.Map#put(K,V)` passing the element you try to add as key, where It checks if there is an element in the current set which has the same hashcode as the **key's**  hashcode(where key is the element you try to insert) and it also checks for equality using equals() method.It only add's to the Set if the hashcode or the equal test fail.If both hashcode and equal test pass then it simply replaces the old value with the current value. Below is the source of both Set#add() and  Map#put().

[**Set#add(E)**](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashSet.java#HashSet.add%28java.lang.Object%29)

```
public boolean add(E e) {
217        return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
218    }
```

[**Map#put(K,V)**](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.put%28java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object%29)

```
 public V put(K key, V value) {
387         if (key == null)
388             return putForNullKey(value);
389         int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
390         int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);
391         for (Entry<K,V> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
392             Object k;
393             if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))) {
394                 V oldValue = e.value;
395                 e.value = value;
396                 e.recordAccess(this);
397                 return oldValue;
398             }
399         }
400 
401         modCount++;
402         addEntry(hash, key, value, i);
403         return null;
404     }
```